# How to parse a JSON file in Ruby version 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-1.9.2, ruby-1.8.7

I have a file called Output.json:

```
[
  {
    "name": "krishna",
    "service": "postman",
    "host": "xxxxxx",
    "doing": [],
    "pool": "xxxxxx",
    "roleType": "yyyyy",
    "simple": true
  }
 ]
```

And this is my Test.rb file:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'pp'

file = File.read('output.json')
data_hash= JSON.parse(file)
pp data_hash
```

When I try to run the script I get:

```
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.4.6/lib/json/common.rb:146:in `parse'
```

How do I print the value "krishna" when I call the name from the JSON file.

Comment: Can you add the full error message please. It seems that you missed the beginning.

Comment: @Uzbekjon It is printing entire json file but in the end it is showing up this error from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.4.6/lib/json/common.rb:146:in `parse'
 from test.rb:9

Comment: `parse` is implemented as a c extension, do you know if your current gem is compiled against your current version of ruby?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Your JSON is valid. You say the filename is "Output.json" but the code shows you're trying to read "output.json". If the file is "Output.json" the code would have a different error. As is your problem can't be duplicated. Also, you tagged Ruby 1.9.2 and Ruby 1.8.7. Which are you using? You shouldn't use either as they're both extremely out-of-date.

Answer (score 0):

Although I never tried version 1.8.7 (only 1.9.3 and higher)

I would assume your problem is that you aren't reading the file correctly. Try File.open instead

Try this:

```
file = File.open('output.json').read
data_hash = JSON.parse(file)
pp data_hash
```

as for printing the value krishna try this (after parsing):

```
puts data_hash['name']  # this outputs krishna
```

Good luck